# return only all right rows that matches left and condition sql

Tags: sql

I have two tables as such

user_first_purchase_date table :

| user ID | first purchase date |
| --- | --- |
| 20 | 01/20/2022 |
| 22 | 03/20/2022 |
| 32 | 04/22/2022 |

user_session table

| session_date | user_id | session source |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12/01/2021 | 20 | facebook ads |
| 01/01/2022 | 20 | facebook ads |
| 01/19/2022 | 20 | facebook ads |
| 01/22/2022 | 20 | facebook ads |
| 02/20/2022 | 23 | facebook ads |
| 03/20/2022 | 23 | facebook ads |
| 02/15/2022 | null | facebook ads |
| 12/01/2021 | 32 | facebook ads |
| 04/22/2022 | 32 | facebook ads |
| 04/23/203 | 32 | facebook ads |

I want to query into a new table where there's a month column, user id, first purchase date, session date and session source. Where
**session date** returned is based on last touch attribution so it means that if user a bought on 1st jan, for the january month it will return the last session_date before the first_purchase_date in that month. The months of both dates must match.

It becomes a table like so:

| month | bought date | session_date | user_id | session source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/20/2022 | 01/19/2022 | 20 | facebook ads |
| 4 | 04/22/2022 | 04/22/2022 | 32 | facebook ads |

I know we have to use inner join, but how to get the where user_id date is between range? and return the month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution; we look for the latest user session before the first purchase:

```
select * 
from user_first_purchase_date fpd
     inner join
     user_session us
     on fpd.[user ID]=us.[user_id]
     and fpd.[first purchase date]>=us.session_date
     and year(fpd.[first purchase date])=year(us.session_date)
     and month(fpd.[first purchase date])=month(us.session_date)
where not exists (select 1
                  from user_session us2
                  where us2.[user_id]=us.[user_id]
                     and us2.[session_date]<=fpd.[first purchase date]
                     and us2.[session_date]>us.[session_date]
                     )
```

There are other ways.
Some parts of this query may not work in all RDBMS products (brackets may not work in Oracle, for example); I assume you know how to convert them (you didn't specify the RDBMS product you are using).

Also, for 'months must match' part; I took this as 'months and years must match'; let us know if this is not the case.
To change the 'in the same month' to 'within 30 days' you can change from:

```
     and year(fpd.[first purchase date])=year(us.session_date)
     and month(fpd.[first purchase date])=month(us.session_date)
```

To:

```
     and us.session_date >= DATE_SUB(fpd.[first purchase date], INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

Update 2022-03-23: If you want the rows from the user_first_purchase_date tbale regardless of the user_session you can use a LEFT JOIN:

```
select * 
from user_first_purchase_date fpd
     left join
     user_session us
     on fpd.[user ID]=us.[user_id]
     and fpd.[first purchase date]>=us.session_date
     and us.session_date >= DATE_SUB(fpd.[first purchase date], INTERVAL 30 DAY)
where 
       us.user_id is null
       OR (
            us.user_id is not null
            and
            not exists (
                  select 1
                  from user_session us2
                  where us2.[user_id]=us.[user_id]
                     and us2.[session_date]<=fpd.[first purchase date]
                     and us2.[session_date]>us.[session_date]
                     )
           )
```

In cases where there is no matching user_session, the left table (user_first_purchase_date) rows will still be returned, and its columns will have their values, and any columns from the right table (user_session us) will show NULL values.

Comment: hi great that works fine until the the not exist part. I am using bigquery GCP and getting a EXISTS subquery is not supported inside join predicate. I am trying to find how to do that.

Comment: moved it to WHERE (same effect because we are using INNER JOIN). Please tag the product you are using.

Comment: thank you, you are a lifesaver. It works fine.

Comment: I tried changing it to first seen session in the last 30 days from user session table, how do I handle null or not found values?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with the null or not found parts; your example removed the not found parts (user:22, for example) so I did the same. If the user_id is null you have no way of associating it with the user_first_purchase table anyway.

Comment: hi got one more question, if I want the not found parts to return the id only? the session  source as null and other parts as null? how do i achieve that?

Comment: Try left join. You haven't accepted the answer, though!